# Asus Transformer Pad TF103C ubuntu android dual boot?

Tags: android, asus, tablet

Has anybody got the Asus Transformer Pad TF103C running with Ubuntu and Android via dual boot?

Any pointers to website explaining the current investigations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've seen, there is currently no way to boot linux. The TF103 doesn't use BIOS, and instead uses Droidboot as it's boot loader.

There isn't much information on Droidboot with Bay Trail devices, or my google-fu isn't the best. Either way there doesn't appear to be easily accessible information about how droidboot on the TF103 works or how one is even able to modify it to boot different OSes.