# Can Ubuntu replace Android on Asus Transformer Pad TF103C

Tags: system-installation, asus, tablet, compatibility

Can Ubuntu replace Android on Asus Transformer Pad TF103C with detachable keyboard?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Asus Transformer Pad TF103C ubuntu android dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534811/asus-transformer-pad-tf103c-ubuntu-android-dual-boot)

The tablet hybrid doesn't use BIOS, it uses droidboot for the boot sequencing...

> As far as I've seen, there is currently no way to boot linux. The
>   TF103 doesn't use BIOS, and instead uses Droidboot as it's boot
>   loader.
>
> There isn't much information on Droidboot with Bay Trail devices, or
>   my google-fu isn't the best. Either way there doesn't appear to be
>   easily accessible information about how droidboot on the TF103 works
>   or how one is even able to modify it to boot different OSes.

There might be another option, though. Rooting it seems possible on https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/asus-transformer-pad-tf103c-tablet-root-t2802995/page29 and after that, you could theoretically install an emulation app to install ubuntu in a container.. Kind of like a VM.

Hope that helps.